# Mocha retry whole suite not only failing test

Tags: mocha.js

I'm trying to configure mocha to retry a whole suite if any test fails.

I navigate to a URL then  populate a form and submit, then the users get redirected and if some element is found the last test passes.

If the element is not found i need to navigate to the form again, fill it and submit, re-running the whole suite N times.

I have tried with this.retries() at *describe* and *it* levels, also bail and retries flags but mocha ONLY retries the failing test.

```
var count = 0

describe('Main suite', function () {

  this.retries(5)

  it('Some setup', () => {
    console.log('1. Some setup');    
  });

  it("bail issue", function() {
    console.log('2. bail issue');
    if (count < 4) {
      count += 1
      throw new Error("Must be retried")
    }
  })

});

describe('end', function () {
  it('close', () => {
  });
});
```

[mocha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcSML.png)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Mocha documentation, `retries` purpose is for failed tests only

> You can choose to retry failed tests up to a certain number of times.
>   This feature is designed to handle end-to-end tests (functional
>   tests/Selenium…) where resources cannot be easily mocked/stubbed. It’s
>   not recommended to use this feature for unit tests.

Ref: 
- https://mochajs.org/#retry-tests